# Ionic device ready not firing just on Android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic5

Not sure if this is a capacitor issue or an ionic issue but platform ready isn’t firing on Android in Emulators or a real device. It fires fine on iOS.

I’m guessing this big error has something to do with it:

```
2020-06-19 22:09:08.669 30272-30490/appIdentifier E/PluginManager: Uncaught exception from plugin
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:339)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:433)
        at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:556)
        at com.ionicframework.common.IonicCordovaCommon.getStringResourceByName(IonicCordovaCommon.java:341)
        at com.ionicframework.common.IonicCordovaCommon.getNativeConfig(IonicCordovaCommon.java:425)
        at com.ionicframework.common.IonicCordovaCommon.getPreferences(IonicCordovaCommon.java:384)
        at com.ionicframework.common.IonicCordovaCommon.execute(IonicCordovaCommon.java:92)
        at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:98)
        at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:132)
        at com.getcapacitor.MessageHandler.callCordovaPluginMethod(MessageHandler.java:69)
        at com.getcapacitor.MessageHandler.postMessage(MessageHandler.java:45)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

and

```
2020-06-19 22:09:07.498 30272-30272/appIdentifier D/Capacitor: Registering plugin: Device
2020-06-19 22:09:13.362 30272-30272/appIdentifier I/Capacitor/Console: File: capacitor-runtime.js - Line 2188 - Msg: deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
2020-06-19 22:09:14.070 30272-30272/appIdentifier W/Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/main-es2015.05060ed6cc850a2d43a7.js - Line 1 - Msg: Ionic Native: deviceready did not fire within 5000ms. This can happen when plugins are in an inconsistent state. Try removing plugins from plugins/ and reinstalling them.
```

I can’t workout where to delete the plugins from as the last line says and I don’t want to remove the platform as I will loose some set up that I have done for the platform and will need to re-add keys etc.

Any clues on where to go? I’ve upgraded to capacitor latest so on 2.2.0, I’ve re sync’d the project as well and no change. One one emulator it just doesn’t even load.

Comment: I can only speculate without any code to look at. First check your application code (Angular/TS). Then do all the clean up you can do in Android Studio (Invalidate cache, clean, etc.). If you have not changed anything inside the android project, just remove it and add the platform again.

Comment: Just delete the entire plugins directory. It will re-install next time you build/run

Comment: @E.Maggini There is no plugins directory in a Capacitor project.

Comment: @Sébastien Hah. This is why I stay away from capacitor then. :)  It is still half baked and gives wrong information --- > " Try removing plugins from plugins/ and reinstalling them."

Comment: @E.Maggini not sure what your source is, there may be plugin directories in a native project, but not in any way similar to the root plugins directory in a Cordova project.

Comment: @E.Maggini yeah this is what is throwing me off, there isn't a plugins director for Android that i can delete (well, that I can see anyway) there is for iOS but I don't have the problem there. My next plan on this is to try and call a method from each plugin in start up to see which one fails. I am calling plugins in a couple of places outside of the platform.ready() function and they are all working fine so it must be one of them failing to initialise properly stopping this promise completing firing

Comment: Looks like you app is missing the ionic deploy plugin strings that associate your app with the appflow project. How does your strings.xml looks like? How did you integrate appflow?

Comment: @jcesarmobile strings.xml is there and looks ok I think. 
```<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">SquadWOD</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">SquadWOD</string>
    <string name="package_name">com.skbarker.squadWOD</string>
    <string name="custom_url_scheme">com.skbarker.squadWOD</string>
</resources>```

Comment: It should contain the appflow app strings, so doesn’t look right. Try running ionic deploy add

Comment: So you were right that my AppFlow config was messed up, that is now fixed and the strings files has the new information in however it didn't fix the device ready problem :-(